# Laravel - Illegal offset type HasMany()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My code:

```
$user = User::where('uid', $user_id)->with('groups.sub_groups')->firstOrFail();
return $user;
```

On my User model:

```
return $this->hasMany('group');
```

On my Group model:

```
return $this->hasMany('sub_group');
```

Now the stack trace gives me the error:

```
Illegal offset type
Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php

    $foreign = $this->getPlainForeignKey();

    // First we will create a dictionary of models keyed by the foreign key of the
    // relationship as this will allow us to quickly access all of the related
    // models without having to do nested looping which will be quite slow.
    foreach ($results as $result)
    {
        $dictionary[$result->{$foreign}][] = $result;
    }
```

---

**update**

removing `.sub_group` doesn't return an error.

```
// works
$user = User::where('uid', $user_id)->with('groups')->firstOrFail();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about that relationship?

Must be hasMany and belongsTo is your Group Model